# Can the sufficient statistics simplify Bayesian model selection?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection

When selecting a model within the Bayesian framework we can choose the model having highest probability given the data. This is proportional to the marginal likelihood or evidence for the data when we assume equally likely prior probabilities on the models. The integration over a particular model's parameters to calculate the evidence associated with that model can be difficult. Rather than use the evidence for the data, wouldn't it be easier to use the 'evidence' for the sufficient statistics associated with the data under that model? e.g., rather than integrate over the mean and precision parameters of a Gaussian model for the evidence of a particular observed data set, why not use the empirical mean and covariance of that data set (i.e., it's sufficient stats under this model) and maximize that match? Here the parameters are the sufficient stats so no integration is required, the prior distribution is the distribution of the sufficient stats, and the prior model selected is the one that maximizes the probability of the empirical mean and cov (MAP for sufficient stats). This seems a natural solution to my intuitive question: What about the observed dataset is selecting the best model(prior)? Doesn't the data inform the model (parameters) through it's sufficient stats?

And then wouldn't the prior(model) thereby selected be the simplest, selected via this MAP procedure, be a Dirac delta function of hyper-parameters (mean, cov) = (m_MLE, 0)? See also [Models vs parameters in Bayes models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/507044/60169).

Comment: When comparing several models, the sufficient statistics are model dependent, that is, they may differ between models. And even when a statistic is sufficient for each of the models, it may prove insufficient for the model comparison, in the sense that the Bayes factor based on that statistic may differ from the Bayes factor based on the entire data. See this [PNAS paper of us](https://www.pnas.org/content/108/37/15112.short) as an illustration.

Comment: Yes, the sufficient stats depend on model family, so this simplified method of adjusting prior’s (hyper-)parameters to maximize probability of  them would only select within a particular family of models i.e., select the hyper parameters of the prior distribution conjugate to the likelihood which maximize probability of observed sufficient stats. For Gaussian models, likelihood is characterized by parameters mean,cov, their distribution in turn given by the conjugate normal-Wishart distribution thereof, so just find the hyper parameters maximizing observed empirical mean,cov.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to read the paper soon. also I'll try testing my proposed hypothesis that maximizing evidence gives Dirac delta in simple one parameter (mean) Gaussian model assuming know precision to see how it actually works out.